# Geoserver mvn install success, maven eclipse build success but Eclipse fails to run project

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, eclipse, ubuntugis, maven

I am able to download geoserver source code , build it with maven , create maven eclipse project but when i load the project from /src in the eclipse it does not run. after checking build path i found that M2_REPO structure is not as what the build path is expecting.

Here are my  computer details on ubuntu 14.04

**JAVA**

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

**maven**

Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"[image]

[image]

**Update**

Tried to build the same thing with lower version (2.10) in windows it worked.
Ununtu still does not work

Comment: that all looks as expected - what are you trying to run? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/eclipse-guide/#running-and-debugging

Comment: I am stuck here http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/quickstart/index.html   When i run the gs-web-app start.java there is error that points to maven repository. Now i am redoing all over for 2.11 instead of master . lets hope this time it works .

Comment: Please edit the question to show the error you get

Comment: @Andrea Aime can you suggest please ?